# Manually adding special characters to a pdf

Tags: r, pdf, utf-8, pdf-generation

I have a pdf (of a simple line graph) which was generated using R, and is just stored with plain text streams. The data used to generate the graph has been lost, and I would like to modify the axis labels by editing the pdf.

I found this line:

```
/F2 1 Tf 12.00 0.00 -0.00 12.00 238.73 18.72 Tm (**Error Rate**) Tj
```

Which appears to control the axis label I want (which currently says "Error Rate"). Changing it to say:

```
/F2 1 Tf 12.00 0.00 -0.00 12.00 238.73 18.72 Tm (**Different Label**) Tj
```

Does indeed result in the axis label changing to "Different Label".

Now, I want the new label to be "Mu". As in, the greek letter Mu. I know this is possible, since I can generate pdf's in R with greek letters in their axis labels.

My first thought was to manually enter the UTF-8 charactor for Mu using the vim trigraph ctrl+k m*, and also through the character map and the like, to give:

```
/F2 1 Tf 12.00 0.00 -0.00 12.00 238.73 18.72 Tm ( μ ) Tj
```

If I attempt to write the file after doing this, I get an error message "CONVERSION ERROR in line xyz", where xyz is the modified line. Opening the saved pdf reveals a '?' for the axis label.

How does the pdf encode mu? How can I modify the label accordingly?

Comment: So, the crux is, I don't know much at all about pdf encoding. I think F2 is specified by this: 
11 0 obj <<
/Type /Font
/Subtype /Type1
/Name /F2
/BaseFont /Helvetica
/Encoding 10 0 R
>> endobj

Comment: why don't you generate a test graph with a Greek mu in the label (along with some distinct text, e.g. `text(expression("LABEL GOES HERE"*mu))` or something) and explore the PDF to see how R encoded it?

Comment: @BenBolker Did this, but result is encoded in a different format apparently, and I cannot find my "LABLE GOES HERE" string anywhere.

Comment: you need to use `compress=FALSE`; see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this:

```
pdf("testmu.pdf",compress=FALSE)
plot(1:10,1:10,xlab="abc",ylab=expression("LABEL "*mu))
dev.off()
```

and found the following chunk in the resulting file:

```
BT
/F2 1 Tf 0.00 12.00 -12.00 0.00 10.28 235.40 Tm (LABEL ) Tj
ET
BT
/F6 1 Tf 0.00 12.00 -12.00 0.00 10.28 276.09 Tm (m) Tj
ET
```

So I suspect if you use

```
/F6 1 Tf 12.00 0.00 -0.00 12.00 238.73 18.72 Tm ( m ) Tj
```

in your example above it should work.  I don't know whether R always defines `F6` (Symbol font), so you might also need to hack in something along these lines:

```
13 0 obj
<< /Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F6 /BaseFont /Symbol
>>
```

**edit**: as pointed out in the other answer, and the comment below it, it seems you also need to manually update the xref count by (I think) searching for `xref`, finding a chunk like

```
xref
0 13
```

and incrementing the second value ...

Comment: Figured this out myself about 5 seconds earlier. You have to manually update the xref table too, but this is easy if you add F6 to the end, since the bytecount is only adjusted for the new entry.

Answer (score 4):

PDF files are binary files, modifying them as text files will corrupt them in most cases. In order to keep the file valid you need to update the xref table (see the PDF specification for more details). If the byte count of the whole file changes, you will need to update each entry of the xref table for the file to remain valid. Another option could be to remove the xref table all together and pass the resulting file through another tool that can "guess" it for you. I have done this [with ghostscript](https://superuser.com/a/282056/78499) in the past with good results.

About the issue with fonts, which font /F2 corresponds to? Is it partially embedded in the PDF file?
If it is, you probably do not have the required information in the file to add the character μ.

Comment: See my comment in response to your earlier one for the font type.

Comment: This was actually very helpful. Solution was to paste in the symbol font definition at the end of the pdf, manually update the bytecount in the xref table, and then just change the label to "m", which is in the symbol font, mu.

Comment: And Ben's answer below ends up being clear than my ramblings. :) edit: above now.

Answer (score 2):

As @yms pointed out, PDFs are typically *not* editable in a text editor, as they most likely contain binary data *and* have an xref table that needs to be updated if chracters are inserted or deleted in the PDF. If you *must* edit a pdf, use [qpdf](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/) to [edit the PDF](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/files/qpdf-manual.html#ref.qdf).